# PharData extractTo method throws exception with message "path already exists"

Tags: php

I'm using PHP's PharData class to extract files out of a tar archives but I'm seeing a very strange behavior.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
$filePattern = "$homeDirectory/*tgz";
$fileArray = glob($filePattern);
$i = 0;

foreach($fileArray as $file) {
  $phar = new PharData($file);
  $phar->extractTo($homeDirectory."/logs-$i");
  array_push($extractedDirectories, $homeDirectory."/logs-$i");
  $i++;
}
```

The foreach loop should extract each of the archives in the home directory and move them into directories named "logs-*n*" where n is an integer inclusive of 0 below the home directory.  However, I'm getting an exception stating:

```
 Encountered error: exception 'PharException' with message 'Extraction from phar "/home/user/file.tgz" failed: Cannot extract "output" to "/home/user/logs-0/output", path already exists'
```

My first thought was that the archive contained two "output" directories, so I manually extracted the archive and examined the contents; lo and behold, just one output directory.  The other thought that occurred to me was that the loop might be trying to run against the same archive twice, but in both cases neither was occurring.

To reiterate the directory "logs-*n*" doesn't exist until the loop starts working with a particular tar archive.  Then it throws an exception saying that the path for extracting it already exists.

I'm beginning to think that I'm encountering some kind of limitation with the PharData class, or the extractTo method, but none of the documentation on php.net covers anything like this, nor have I found any questions covering something like this on SO, which is why I'm adding this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so after banging my head against this a bit.  The problem was that I was not using the full set of parameters for the extractTo method.  The method accepts one required and two optional parameters, the first optional parameter is a string or array containing specific file names to extract, the second optional parameter is an "overwrite" flag.  When I changed the code to the following:

```
foreach($fileArray as $file) {
  $phar = new PharData($file);
  $phar->extractTo($homeDirectory."/logs-$i", null, true);
  array_push($extractedDirectories, $homeDirectory."/logs-$i");
  $i++;
}
```

Here, I'm just asking to extract all files and also allow for overwriting.  Once I do that the problem is solved.  If you read the [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/phardata.extractto.php) for this method, it says that this flag determines whether or not to overwrite *existing* files.  I'm not really sure why that would be necessary for this to work.  The nearest I can figure for why this occurred is that for some reason the extractTo method saw the parent "output" directory as already existing after its first iteration over the child log files and failed.